# type of function to get jacobian from Numeric.AD

Tags: haskell

I need to construct a function in which to pass a function, from the passed function the jacobian can be computed (and later further explored). I can compute the Jacobian in single steps, but not when   I try to pass the function as an argument into another function. Obviously the type of the function passed is not correct, but what is the correct type?

```
...
import Numeric.AD 
...


lv3explore fun pt = return () 
    where 
        jaco = jacobian fun pt
```

`ghci` gives a type

```
lv3explore :: (MonadIO m, Traversable f, Num a) => p -> f a -> IO ()
```

which produces an error message I cannot make sense. I expected a type

```
lv3explore :: (Show a, Floating a) => ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> IO ()
```

but get a (smaller) error message, from which I do not see how to correct the error:

```
    src/LVmat.hs:88:25: error: [GHC-25897]
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’
                     with ‘Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse s a’
      Expected: [Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse s a]
                -> [Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse s a]
        Actual: [a] -> [a]
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          lv3explore :: forall a.
                        (Show a, Floating a) =>
                        ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> IO ()
        at src/LVmat.hs:84:1-66
    • In the first argument of ‘jacobian’, namely ‘fun’
      In the expression: jacobian fun pt
      In an equation for ‘jaco’: jaco = jacobian fun pt
    • Relevant bindings include
        jaco :: [[a]] (bound at src/LVmat.hs:88:9)
        pt :: [a] (bound at src/LVmat.hs:86:16)
        fun :: [a] -> [a] (bound at src/LVmat.hs:86:12)
        lv3explore :: ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> IO ()
          (bound at src/LVmat.hs:86:1)
   |
88 |         jaco = jacobian fun pt
```

What is the correct type for the function, so the Jacobian can be computed?

Using the advice from @leftaroundabout I encapsulated computing the Jacobian in a function:

```
lv_jacobian ::(Real a, Num a, Fractional a )=> 
     (∀ s. (Reifies s Tape, Typeable s) =>  
         [Reverse s a] -> [Reverse s a])  -> [a] ->  [[a]]
lv_jacobian fun pt =   map (map realToFrac) .  jacobian fun $ pt
```

The function compiles but the AD types escape to any function calling this function with a function `[Double]->[Double]`

```
lv1 :: [Double] -> [Double]
lv1 = lv_fun 2 gvec1 dmat1 
jacob1 = lv_jacobian lv1 pt1
```

`jacobi1` produces an error

```
`Couldn't match type ‘Double’
                     with ‘Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse s Double’`
```

.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this without `-XRankNTypes`: the argument to `jacobian` must be universally quantified. That's why this can actually *only* be implemented with an explicit signature, GHC is in general not able to infer the right type for a higher-rank function.

There are multiple ways this can be done, but the most manifest is to just copy from the signature of `jacobian`, since your function seems to be basically just a wrapper around that:

```
jacobian :: (Traversable f, Functor g, Num a)
      => (∀ s. (Reifies s Tape, Typeable s) => f (Reverse s a) -> g (Reverse s a))
      -> f a -> g (f a)
```

So `lv3explore` is the same, except the final result becomes simply `IO ()`:

```
lv3explore :: (Traversable f, Functor g, Num a)
      => (∀ s. (Reifies s Tape, Typeable s) => f (Reverse s a) -> g (Reverse s a))
      -> f a -> IO ()
```

(presumably also with `Show a`, though that's not needed for the stub you showed). You can make a list-specialised version which is perhaps easier to understand

```
lv3explore :: Num a
      => (∀ s. (Reifies s Tape, Typeable s) => [Reverse s a] -> [Reverse s a])
      -> [a] -> IO ()
```

though I would not really recommend that: conceptually you're dealing with constant-length traversables here (representable functors), which the list instantiation doesn't express at all.

### Tangential rant

Frankly, all this clunky tape stuff that the `ad` library has in its signatures is horrible. Such gymnastics are *not* fundamentally needed for reverse-mode automatic differentiation, as demonstrated in the classic (?) paper [The simple essence of automatic differentiation](https://doi.org/10.1145/3236765) which inexplicably still doesn't seem to have spawned a library to dethrown `ad`. In principle, the signature of `jacobian` should be something like this (types from [linearmap-category](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category)):

```
jacobian :: (LinearSpace v, LinearSpace w)
              => (Differentiable v w) -> v -> (DualVector w +> DualVector v)
```

No traversables and functors and tapes, just mathematically meaningful vector spaces and a dedicated category for the function to be differentiated. (Which could be expressed with compiling-to-categories or [agents](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.2.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#g:8) to allow writing the functions with numerical expressions.)

Comment: Wonderful - including and especially the rant. I would not have gotten it without the help. I started reading the paper by Conal Elliott (whom I admire for other work) but it is, for now, beyond my level of understanding. -- I used the second version. With the first version I had to replace the operator with spelled out `forall` and had it working, but did not understand it. - It is a pitty that a wondeful package to compute Jacobian and others is so difficult to use.

Comment: This morning it worked, but I do not see, what are the relevant changes, such that GHC could match the types. Is there an explicit way to change the type of the function going in, so my function accepts types `[Double]->[Double]` as a function?

Comment: `[Double]->[Double]` can't possibly work, no.